# Property value not set after block finishes

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I'm trying to set a property value inside the following code but when I the block exits that property value is null.

```
- (PRSapoAuth *)initWithUser:(NSString *)user password:(NSString *)password forToken:{

__block NSString *token;

self = [super init];
if (!self) {
    return nil;
}

NSString *urlAuth = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://services.sapo.pt/Codebits/gettoken?user=%@&password=%@", user, password];
NSString *modifiedURL = [urlAuth stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:modifiedURL]];
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
    token = JSON[@"token"];
    self.token = token;
} failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
    token = @"";
    self.token = token;
}];
[operation addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"isFinished" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
[operation start];
while (!operation.isFinished) {
}

return self;

}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
NSLog(@"%@", self.token);
}
```

Anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What debugging / logging have you done?

Comment: Just the NSLog line on the bottom of the code.

Comment: So find out exactly what's in `JSON` and if the `response` is valid...

Comment: JSON has data and is valid.

Comment: And the `JSON`is a dictionary, with a top level key of "token", and it is being extracted properly, and your setter is called with the correct value? Localise the problem, is it the data handling or your observation?

Comment: It's the observation.

Comment: What are you trying to gain from the observation anyway. You can check the source code to see when the `isFinished` flag is updated in relation to the callbacks being called...

Comment: I was using that to see if I can get self.token's new value to be accessible after the asynchronous operation finished.

Answer (score -1):

```
you need to call method in this order.Not sure but will work for you 


   [operation start];
    [operation addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"isFinished" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
```